# Which tables in odi scheme store designer model data?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I want to make a graph of dependency between tables in an Oracle database according to packages that designed in odi.

The odi designer show which table populate and populated by which tables in odi GUI, designer tap, model section.

I want to know which tables in database store this data to write a script to make a graph not doing it by hand.

I use ODI 12C.

Comment: Hi, if I understood well: You want to generate a graph for the tables that are used in an ODI Packages?

Comment: Yes this graph show which tables are used to generate whiches

Comment: In this case, you understand that you can query some ODI Repository tables, such as SNP_TABLE or SNP_MAPPING, but you will receive as a result, rows. This is fine for you? After you will receive the desired rows, it will be possible to generate the graphs?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, the odi show this information simply in gui under models as populated by abd used to populate but this data is not in any table, and I don't know how can I regenerate them

Comment: That means that you need something like [this](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/02/di-tips-odi12c-repo-query-mapping-target-table/). Did you tried something?

Comment: Thank very much you, it's a very useful paper I search so many but I couldn't find something like this. I guess it will solve my issue.